# How do I include image in my app from a url?

Tags: application-development, quickly

How do I add particular images which is situated in given url, in my app , can I do it in glade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Handler:
    def on_window1_delete_event(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit(*args)

def change_image(image):
    the_image = builder.get_object("replaceimage")
    the_image.set_from_file(image)
    the_image.queue_draw()

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("ui/sample.glade")
builder.connect_signals(Handler())
window = builder.get_object("window1")
window.show_all()

change_image("assets/image.png")

Gtk.main()
```

It uses [this glade file](http://pastebin.com/KzLPKKt8).

It does, however, require that you save the image to disk first.

Comment: Thanks But I mean programatically include an image from internet ,ie ,url can be changed during the execution of the program .

Comment: This does that.  You save the file from the url to /tmp or whatever, then drop that local disk location in to choose image.

Comment: thanks , how to download an image using python code ? should I use wget for it ?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

Comment: I tried urllib2.urlopen( image url) , but where is it stored ?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files